# Please let me know how could I put my math.se page on my website.

Tags: support

Please let me know how could I put my math.se page on my website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a page on your web site which is just a copy of your profile, why not simply link to your profile?

If you're looking to produce a snazzy link to your profile, you can use [your flair](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flair):

```
<a href="https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2987/rajesh-d">
<img src="https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flair/2987.png" width="208" height="58" alt="Mathematics profile for Rajesh D at Mathematics, Q&amp;A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields" title="Mathematics profile for Rajesh D at Mathematics, Q&amp;A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields">
</a>
```

[image: Mathematics profile for Rajesh D at Mathematics, Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields]

If you want to do something fancier, like include bits of your profile page surrounded by other content, you should probably look at the [SE API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-stack-exchange-api-reference/) and [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/).